# Login with Facebook using REST API with yii2 PHP

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to implement social media login (Facebook, Twitter , etc..) in my yii2 project. I have one web application and I need to login that webpage with the help of social media login. I would like to implement this with REST API. I have added the facebook app id, app secret in the config.php

```
 'authClientCollection' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
            'clients' => [
                'facebook' => [
                                'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
                                'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
                                'clientId' => '********************',
                                'clientSecret' => '****************',
                                'attributeNames' => ['name', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'],
                            ],

            ],
```

In my customerLoginController I have added the Authaction

```
 public function actions(){
        return [
            'auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' => [$this, 'oAuthSuccess'],
            ],
       ];
    }


    public function oAuthSuccess($client) { 
        $userAttributes = $client->getUserAttributes(); 
        if($userAttributes->email !== NULL){
            // User add in model
        }else{
            // Show error message
        }
    }
```

How to call these authAction in postman, when I tried, it showing error.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Do you pass variables in your POST request?

Comment: In POST request i just pass my email id

Comment: The picture is not showing. What kind of auth are you using to access to your Rest Service? Basic Auth? What's the error you are getting?